# Infinitely many primes of the type 5 mod 6.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Problem: Prove that there are infinitely many primes of the type 5 mod 6.

My professor did the problem and the proof was horribly long. Can someone show me a shorter version of the proof of this problem.

Comment: The general theorem about $b\pmod a$ with $(a,b)=1$ is a long hard slog, but there is an easy proof of this particular case that follows Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: Possibly relevant: All primes except for 2 and 3 are in {1, 5} (mod 6).  So if the theorem from your question were false, ALL prime numbers beyond a certain point would be 1 (mod 6).

Comment: It'll be hard to give a shorter proof without knowing what we're being compared against.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** If $n\equiv 5\pmod 6$, then for some prime factor $p$, $p\equiv 5\pmod 6$.

Then try a variation of Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes.

It is harder to prove that there are infinitely many primes $\equiv 1\pmod 6$.

Answer (score 0):

If we cross out from sequence of positive integers all numbers divisible by 2 and all numbers divisible by 3 then all remaining numbers will be in one of two forms:

$S1(n)=6n+5=5,11,17,...$ or $S2(n)=6n+7=7,13,19,...;$
$n=0,1,2,3,...$

So all prime numbers also will be in one of these two forms.

Comment: see [link]https://www.academia.edu/13890086/Matrix_sieve_the_easiest_way_to_find_prime_numbers